# How to write query using self join and group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have sql server 2008 db table FILE_DETAILS in following format.

```
ID    FileName    Filesize_in_MB
--------------------------------
1     a.txt        5
2     b.txt        2
3     c.txt        2
3     d.txt        4
4     e.txt        6
4     f.txt        1
4     g.txt        2
5     h.txt        8
6     i.txt        7
```

now what i want to fetch is as bellow

```
ID    FileName    Filesize_in_MB
--------------------------------
1     a.txt               5
2     b.txt               2
3     c.txt;d.txt         6
4     e.txt;f.txt;g.txt   9
5     h.txt               8
6     i.txt               7
```

In above results what happens `ID` became unique key and `FILENAME` has get attached and separated by `;`  and also `FILESIZE_IN_MB` field in sum of group by `ID`

I tried with various combination like groupby + self join, also sub queries and all that
but i think i missing something.

is it possible to handle this in SQL query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005 could help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        STUFF(( SELECT ';' + [FileName] 
                FROM FILE_DETAILS 
                WHERE ID = f.ID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), 
        SUM(Filesize_in_MB)
FROM    FILE_DETAILS f
GROUP BY ID
```

Here's some more information:
[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a `group by`. Aggregating `Filesize_IN_MB` can be done using `sum` as aggregator. However, to aggregate `FileName` you may need to [create an AGGREGATE in SQL SERVER 2008R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741.aspx). This will allow you to use `Concatenate` as an aggregation function.

```
select Concatenate(FileName), sum(Filesize_IN_MB) FROM FILE_DETAILS group by ID
```

There is another way of [aggregate concatenation](http://p2p.wrox.com/sql-language/1661-aggregate-concatenation.html) which seems fairly simple but I haven't tried.